# tikz Shifting node horizonally

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I have the following code,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{cloral}{RGB}{230, 110, 108}
\definecolor{conv}{RGB}{148, 183, 247}
\definecolor{layers}{RGB}{108, 230, 149}
% Define block styles

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, minimum width=10em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block]  (init)[fill=layers, xshift=-10, minimum width=12em] {\hspace{-1em}Filter concatenation};
    \node [block, below of=init, fill=conv] (oneconv) {1X1 convolutions};
    \node [block, right of=oneconv, fill=conv] (threeconv) {3X3 convolutions};
    \node [block, right of=threeconv, fill=conv] (fiveconv) {5X5 convolutions};
    \node [block, right of=fiveconv, fill=cloral] (maxpooling) {3X3 max pooling};

    \node [block, below of=threeconv, fill=layers] (prev) {Previous Layer};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (oneconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (threeconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (fiveconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (maxpooling) -- (init);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (oneconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (threeconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (fiveconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (maxpooling);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Basically, I just want to shift the first node such that it is in the middle of the flow chart. I have tried using `xshift` but it appears to make no difference at all.

[image]

Comment: All the other nodes are placed relative to your first node. So changing that won't have any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of positioning the 4 middle nodes in relation to the top one, I position the top one and the bottom one in relation to the center of these 4 nodes.

To do this I create an auxiliary node (aux) located in the middle of the two nodes `(threeconv)` and `(fiveconv)` using the `calc` library.

```
\node (aux) at ($(threeconv)!.5!(fiveconv)$){};
\node [block,above of=aux]  (init)[fill=layers, minimum width=12em] {\hspace{-1em}Filter concatenation};

\node [block, below of=aux, fill=layers] (prev) {Previous Layer};
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{cloral}{RGB}{230, 110, 108}
\definecolor{conv}{RGB}{148, 183, 247}
\definecolor{layers}{RGB}{108, 230, 149}
% Define block styles

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, minimum width=10em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
    % Place nodes

    \node [block,fill=conv] (oneconv) {1X1 convolutions};
    \node [block, right of=oneconv, fill=conv] (threeconv) {3X3 convolutions};
    \node [block, right of=threeconv, fill=conv] (fiveconv) {5X5 convolutions};
    \node [block, right of=fiveconv, fill=cloral] (maxpooling) {3X3 max pooling};
    \node (aux) at ($(threeconv)!.5!(fiveconv)$){};
    \node [block,above of=aux]  (init)[fill=layers, minimum width=12em] {\hspace{-1em}Filter concatenation};

    \node [block, below of=aux, fill=layers] (prev) {Previous Layer};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (oneconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (threeconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (fiveconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (maxpooling) -- (init);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (oneconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (threeconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (fiveconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (maxpooling);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to load any additional library, nor do complicated computations. All you need to do is to put the four nodes in the middle in a matrix. (BTW, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, and you can draw the arrows in a loop.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{cloral}{RGB}{230, 110, 108}
\definecolor{conv}{RGB}{148, 183, 247}
\definecolor{layers}{RGB}{108, 230, 149}
% Define block styles

\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, minimum
    width=10em},
line/.style={draw, -latex'}}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block]  (init)[fill=layers, xshift=-10, minimum width=12em] {\hspace{-1em}Filter concatenation};
    \matrix[below of=init,column sep=1em] (mat){
    \node [block,  fill=conv] (oneconv) {1X1 convolutions}; &
    \node [block, fill=conv] (threeconv) {3X3 convolutions}; &
    \node [block,  fill=conv] (fiveconv) {5X5 convolutions}; &
    \node [block, fill=cloral] (maxpooling) {3X3 max pooling};\\
    };

    \node [block, below of=mat, fill=layers] (prev) {Previous Layer};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (oneconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (threeconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (fiveconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (maxpooling) -- (init);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (oneconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (threeconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (fiveconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (maxpooling);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With use of the TikZ libraries `calc` and `chains` and drawing connection lines in the loop, you code become much shorter and clear:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning}

\definecolor{cloral}{RGB}{230, 110, 108}
\definecolor{conv}{RGB}{148, 183, 247}
\definecolor{layers}{RGB}{108, 230, 149}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 17mm and 2mm,
  start chain = A going right,
box/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=#1,
              minimum width=9em, minimum height=6ex, align=center,
              on chain=A},
box/.default = conv,
arr/.style = {-Latex}
                        ]
% Place nodes
% midle row
\node   [box]  {$1 \times 1$ convolutions};
\node   [box]  {$3 \times 3$ convolutions};
\node   [box]  {$5 \times 5$ convolutions};
\node   [box=cloral]{$3 \times 3$ max pooling};
% top
\node   [box= green!30,
         above=of $(A-1.north)!0.5!(A-4.north)$]    {Filter concatenation};
% bottom
\node   [box= green!30,
         below=of $(A-1.south)!0.5!(A-4.south)$]    {Previous Layer};
% Draw edges
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
{
\draw[arr]  (A-\i) -- (A-5);
\draw[arr]  (A-6) -- (A-\i);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A way of drawing:

- first is drawn chain of nodes with names `A-1`, ... `A-4` with use of `chains` library
- above of middle of the nodes chain is positioned top nodes with use of `calc` and `positioning` library top nodes
- similarly as top node is added bottom node
- connections lines are drawn in the loop. In it is exploited nodes' naming `A-1`, `A-2`, etc.
- in definitions of nodes and arrows styles are moved in `ikzpicture` options and are used recent style syntax ( ˙\tikzstyle` is obsolete)

Answer (score 1):

All the other nodes are placed relative to your first node `init`. So changing that won't have any effect. `xshift` the left most node `oneconv` to get center aligned first node.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{cloral}{RGB}{230, 110, 108}
\definecolor{conv}{RGB}{148, 183, 247}
\definecolor{layers}{RGB}{108, 230, 149}
% Define block styles

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, minimum width=10em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block]  (init)[fill=layers, minimum width=12em] {\hspace{-1em}Filter concatenation};
    \node [block, below of=init, fill=conv,xshift=-6cm] (oneconv) {1X1 convolutions};
    \node [block, right of=oneconv, fill=conv] (threeconv) {3X3 convolutions};
    \node [block, right of=threeconv, fill=conv] (fiveconv) {5X5 convolutions};
    \node [block, right of=fiveconv, fill=cloral] (maxpooling) {3X3 max pooling};

    \node [block, below of=threeconv, fill=layers,xshift=2cm] (prev) {Previous Layer};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (oneconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (threeconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (fiveconv) -- (init);
    \path [line] (maxpooling) -- (init);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (oneconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (threeconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (fiveconv);
    \path [line] (prev) -- (maxpooling);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```